# R round a date with timezone

Tags: r, datetime

```
timestamp = 1491800340000
```

I'm having trouble with some date manipulation in R. The timestamp above is:

```
2017-04-10T04:59:00.000 GMT
2017-04-09T23:59:00.000 America/Bogota (Local time)
```

I want to round it to `2017-04-09T00:00:00.000 GMT` because my daily aggregations are set to 00:00 GMT.

How can I do that?
Here's what I tried:

```
> Sys.timezone()
  [1] "America/Bogota"
> timestamp = 1491800340000
> date = strptime(timestamp / 1000, "%s");
  [1] "2017-04-09 23:59:00 COT"
> midnightLocal = trunc(date, "day");
  [1] "2017-04-09 COT"
> midnightUTC = strptime(format(midnightLocal, "%Y-%m-%d"), "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "UTC");
  [1] "2017-04-09 UTC"
> truncatedtimestamp = as.integer(format(midnightUTC, "%s"));
  [1] 1491714000
```

which is `2017-04-09T05:00:00.000 GMT` (not midnight as I expected). Looks like I failed to specify the timezone somewhere?

I tried many things like POSIXct but did not succeed.
Any hint is appreciated!
Cheers

*ps: I'd prefer not to install any package*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little trickery:

```
timestamp = 1491800340000

ts <- as.POSIXct(timestamp / 1000, origin = "1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT")
ts2 <- as.Date(trunc(ts, "day"))
attr(ts2, "tzone") <- "GMT"
format(ts2, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z") # to prove it's midnight
# [1] "2017-04-09 00:00:00 UTC"
class(ts2)
# [1] "Date"
```

From here you have a couple of options: a little brute-force (numeric conversion) or perhaps the more time-friendly/safe way.

Brute-force numeric:

```
ts3a <- as.numeric(ts2) * 60*60*24
ts3a
# [1] 1491696000
as.POSIXct(ts3a, origin = "1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT", tz = "GMT")
# [1] "2017-04-09 GMT"
```

Time-friendly/safe:

```
ts3b <- as.POSIXct(ts2)
attr(ts3b, "tzone") <- "GMT"
ts3b
# [1] "2017-04-09 GMT"
```

(Since they are `POSIXct`, it's showing the date only because it is midnight; you can easily prove it's correct.)

Comment: `attr(ts3b, "tzone") <- "GMT"` that's what I missed! Thank you!